# Instantiating object where constructor takes abstract parameterized type in Java

Tags: java, generics

I have classes similar to those shown below, and need to instantiate a Container object as on line (*).

```
public abstract class Foo {
    ...
}

public class Bar extends Foo {
    ...
}

public class Container {
    public Container(ArrayList<Foo> fooList) {
        this.fooList = fooList;
    }
    ...
    private ArrayList<Foo> fooList;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    ArrayList<Bar> barList = new ArrayList<Bar>();
(*) Container container = new Container(barList);
}
```

However, I get the following compilation error:

```
error: incompatible types: ArrayList<Bar> cannot be converted to ArrayList<Foo>
```

Is there a workaround to this? I need Container to be able to take ArrayLists of different subclasses that extend Foo.

Comment: Try using ArrayList<? extends Foo> as the parameter type.

Comment: Be aware that mixed collections can end in tears, which often start when you start having to type-check

Answer (score 0):

Change your `Container` class and `main()` method as shown below.

```
class Container {
    public Container(List<Foo> fooList) {
        this.fooList = fooList;
    }
    private List<Foo> fooList;
}
```

```
public class Solution {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Foo> barList = new ArrayList<>();

        barList.add(new Bar());

        Container container = new Container(barList);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If on whatever reason you cannot change the `Container` class, the only solution would be:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ArrayList<Foo> barList = new ArrayList<Foo>();
    barList.add(new Bar());
    Container container = new Container(barList);
}
```

However it's a rather bad design for three reason:

1. Container class enforces usage of `ArrayList` over other implementations of `List` interface
2. Container class enforces usage of list of `Foo` instances and doesn't accept lists of subclasses of `Foo`
3. Container class can store any descedants of `Foo` and it is not configurable

First issue can be solved by changing `ArrayList` to `List`.

```java
public class Container {
    public Container(List<Foo> fooList) {
        this.fooList = fooList;
    }
    private List<Foo> fooList;
}
```

Second issue can be solved by using Generics

```java
public class Container {
    public Container(List<? extends Foo> fooList) {
        this.fooList = fooList;
    }
    private List<? extends Foo> fooList;
}
```

Last issue can be solved by parametrizing `Container` class itself:

```java
public class Container<T extends Foo> {
    public Container(List<? extends T> fooList) {
        this.fooList = fooList;
    }
    private List<? extends T> fooList;
}
```

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ArrayList<Bar> barList = new ArrayList<>();
    Container<Foo> container = new Container<>(barList);
}
```

If you want to make sure that particular list implementation will have fast `O(1)` get by index operation you can only accept classes which implement both `List` and `RandomAccess` interfaces.

```java
public class Container {
    public <L extends List<? extends Foo> & RandomAccess> Container(L fooList) {
        this.fooList = fooList;
    }
    private List<? extends Foo> fooList;
}
```